# Oauth2.0 + Single Page web app : how to switch from http to https (SSL) without leaving the web app

Tags: jquery-mobile, web-applications, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, single-page-application

I am implementing Single Sign On in my web app (the app will be released as a pure web app, or hybrid app using phonegap build).
I use a single page format and Jquery Mobile.

Google+ API Oauth2.0 seems to requires SSL (https).
So, I am confused: how do I switch from http to https (ssl) protocol with out leaving my single-page app ?

Thanks for your help.